# How to parametrise a parabola with a specific domain

Tags: conic-sections, parametric

What would be the best method to find the parametric equations for the parabola 
$y = (x-2)^2$ over a given domain of $(2 ≤ t ≤ 5)$?

The figure I've been given has the parabola starting from $(2,0)$ and ending at $(5,9)$.

I need to find both $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, is there an easy was of doing this?

Comment: What about $x(t)=t$ and $y(t)=(t-2)^2$?

Comment: I didn't even realise that, I must've been over thinking it. Thanks

Comment: You can also have $(x,y)=(u+2,u^2)$ where $u$ is the slope of the line from the vertex $(2,0)$ to the point $(x,y)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the set $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid y = (x-2)^{2} \}$ is the parabola under consideration, if $\varphi: t \mapsto (t, (t-2)^{2})$ on $[2,5]$ then $\varphi[2,5]$ is the segment of the parabola joining $(2,0)$ and $(5,9)$.